# The appropriate way to loop inside a d3 filter (or, how to select multiple features)

Tags: json, loops, d3.js, topojson

Let's say I have an array like this, which I want to use for pattern matching:

```
var mich = ["Michigan", "Connecticut", "Florida", "New York"];
var arrayLength = mich.length;
```

And I have a topojson object like this, nested inside a basic d3.json function that's accessing a topojson file:

```
var allstates = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.layer1);
```

Which I filter using:

```
var fromstate = allstates.features.filter()[0];
```

How can I find all objects within the topojson.features that match my array? A loop through the array inside the filter only matches the first object. I.e., this fails inside the filter:

```
function (d){ for (i=0; i<arrayLength; i++){ return d.properties.NAME == mich[i];}
```

Please let me know if more notation is needed.

Comment: you want all objects which have that name?

Comment: @Mritunjay I want all objects that match the strings in the mich array.

Comment: can you post the full code, I think this is only the function just given to filter.

Comment: @Mritunjay Which code o you want exactly? The json file etc..?

Comment: from where that `d` is coming that will be called on an `Array` probably. that code, So I can replicate your problem

Comment: @Mritunjay Something like this: var allstates = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.layer1);
 //console.log(allstates.features);
 var fromstate = allstates.features.filter(function (d){ for (i=0; i<arrayLength; i++){ return d.properties.NAME == mich[i];}})[0];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57644/discussion-between-mritunjay-and-in-code-veritas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in your function

```
return mich.indexOf(d.properties.NAME) >= 0;
```

instead of

```
for (i=0; i<arrayLength; i++){ return d.properties.NAME == mich[i];}
```

Here what it will do, it will check that if `d.property.NAME` & `mich[0]` are equal, if both are equal then it will return `true` otherwise it'll return `false`.

Comment: This works and doesn't. The issue is it returns an array of objects, each of which could work as a data object for d3. so you'd need another loop over those objects to display each of them.

Comment: @Incodeveritas that was another issue, but I answered what you asked in your question, the question was why it's showing only one Item after `filter`.

Comment: True! But what would you do for this issue?

Comment: if you just wanted to display all of them, loop and display, what is problem with that. I'm not very familiar to d3 sorry. that was a javascript problem.

Comment: It's not true to d3 architecture

Comment: I'm not getting what do you want now, I'm not familiar to d3 much.

Answer (score 1):

```
var mich = ["Michigan", "Connecticut", "Florida", "New York"];
var allstates = topojson.feature(us, us.objects.layer1);
var fromstate = allstates.features.filter( function (d){
        for (i=0; i<mich.length; i++){ 
            if (d.properties.NAME == mich[i]) {
                return true;
            }
            //otherwise the loop continues
        }
        //if none of them matched
        return false;
    });
```

Or if you don't need to support IE<9:

```
var fromstate = allstates.features.filter( function (d){
    return mich.indexOf(d.properties.NAME) != -1;
});
```